# Url rewriting on nginx server+ispconfig3

Tags: regex, url, url-rewriting

A simple question for url rewriting.

I would like that every request that comes on website and looks like this:

http://www.website.com/and/default.asp?is=xxx&pn=xxx&ver=xxx&sy=xxx
gets rewritten to 
http://d.website.com/and/default.asp?is=xxx&pn=xxx&ver=xxx&sy=xxx

I'm sure the answer is simple but I cant make it work.

We are using nginx + ispconfig3 combo for our site.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself.

rewrite ^/and/(.*)$ http://d.website.com/and/$1;

Place this line in website vhost file.